# Selecting elements from vector by index range

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, vector

Despite some googling I can't find anything about how to do this.

If I want to take some elements of an array I can do

```
var partOfArray = myArray[firstIndex..lastIndex];
var anotherpartOfArray = myArray[firstIndex..^1];
```

Can I do the same for something of type Vector? Something like

```
// Vector<double> myVector; 
var partOfVector = myVector(firstIndex..lastIndex);
```

Currently my only workaround is to convert the vector back to an array, index it, then convert it back to a vector.  There must be an easier way to do this.

Edit: It has been pointed out that range indexing is just not supported for MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra types.  I have found the best solution would be to use:

var partOfVector = myVector.SubVector(startIndex, samplesToTake);

Comment: The [System.Numerics.Vector<T> Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector-1?view=net-5.0) has transformations from and to `Span<T>` / `ReadOnlySpan<T>`. Probably you will get a better slicing performance with `Span<T>` compared to arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: This answer is made assuming `System.Numerics.Vector` is used.

This does not seem to be available due to the "Countable" requirement for using [implicit range indexing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges):

> 1. The type is Countable.
> 2. The type has an accessible instance indexer which takes a single int as the argument.
> 3. The type does not have an accessible instance indexer which takes an Index as the first parameter. The Index must be the only parameter or the remaining parameters must be optional.

"Countable" in this context means having a `Count` or `Length` instance property, `Vector<T>` only have a static Count property.

Note that `Vector<T>` is intended for high performance SIMD optimizations, i.e. it is **not** equivalent to a c++ vector, and this unfortunately often means convenience will be sacrificed for performance. If you are converting the vector back to an array and back again will probably significantly reduce the benefit of vectorization. It is difficult to provide better suggestions without knowing the specific application.

I would also suggest reading about [SIMD intrinstics](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/hardware-intrinsics-in-net-core/). My takeaway from that article is that the gains from `Vector<T>` is rather modest compared to that of intrinstics, even if the later ends up being platform specific.

Comment: It might well be that it just isn't possible as you say. There is a function called subvector which makes a new copy of part of the vector indexed from a start and a count which may be enough.

Comment: @David Holdaway Do you have a link to the subvector function? I have difficult finding it in the documentation.

Comment: https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double/DenseVector.htm#SubVector

Comment: @David Holdaway My answer is assuming `System.Numerics.Vector` is used. If you are using `MathNet.Numerics` vector it likely fails the requirement for a indexer.  But there is a `.Values` property to access the array, presumably the actual array and not a copy. However, Math.Numerics is more targeted at math application and not real time usage, so some overhead is probably expected when you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Range indexing just isn't supported for MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra so the closest you can do is the following:

```
var partOfVector = myVector.SubVector(firstIndex, lastIndex - firstIndex + 1);
```